# Complex Trigonometry using a Complex Triangle

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

When using the trigonometric functions with real numbers we often use a right triangle to visualize and simplify certain calculations. The same can be done when using the trigonometric functions with complex numbers with the triangle shown below:

[image: complex right triangle]

In this triangle all the sides and angles are complex. Additionally, those sides and angles satisfy the following properties:

$$
z_1+z_2=z_3=\frac{\pi}{2}\\
w_1^2+w_2^2=w_3^2\\
$$

All the complex trigonometric functions obey the expected SOHCAHTOA relations on this triangle, and the inverse functions behave as expected as well. In particular, deriving the inverse trigonometric functions is made very easy by using this approach. For example, if we are given that:

$$\sin^{-1}u=-i\ln\left(iu+\sqrt{1-u^2}\right)$$

and we are asked to derive a similar formula for $\cos^{-1}u$ then we can simply draw a complex right triangle with $w_1=\sqrt{1-u^2}, w_2=u, w_3=1$, from which it is immediately clear that:

$$\cos^{-1}u=\sin^{-1}\left[\sqrt{1-u^2}\right]=-i\ln\left[i\sqrt{1-u^2}+\sqrt{1-\left[\sqrt{1-u^2}\right]^2}\right]\\
=-i\ln\left(u+i\sqrt{1-u^2}\right)$$

The only drawback with this approach is that the real lengths and angles of the triangle have no connection with the complex sides and angles. If anything, the shape of the triangle should just be treated as a visual mnemonic.

My question is this: why have I never heard of this approach being used when dealing with trigonometric functions of complex variables?